# Page centering messes up

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm making a website and it is here: http://animactions.ca/Animactions/accueil.php

My problem is when I go from accueil to contact, I notice the page shifts a bit. I cant figure out why though, the body is supposed to be a fixed width.Thanks
*Bear in mind my resolution is 1680x1050, it doesn't do this on 1280x800

Comment: Browser? It looks fine to me in Chrome on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because the scrollbar appears when you go to Contact, since the page isn't long enough with your resolution to need one on Accueil.

Edit : mais pourquoi je parle en anglais moi ? :) Bref c'est juste la présence ou non de l'ascenceur de Firefox qui fait que la page semble bouger, c'est normal.